# gazebo_ros_control missing in latest ros-jade-gazebo-ros-pkgs

Tags: ros

I still cannot figure it out but find an alternative way to build the project. Hello, When running "catkin_make" , I got "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo_ros_control" with any of the following names"

From Gazebo website, http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ro... , they mentioned that "Note: currently in ROS Jade there is no ros-jade-gazebo-ros-control package released."

From http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ro... , "The 2.5.3 Jade version will include the gazebo_ros_control: ros/rosdistro#11044".

However, is there any way I can either

1. build gazebo_ros_control from the source code and install in my local jade (/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks)

or

2. ignore gazebo_ros_control

Thank you for taking time on my questions

Comment: did you try [this](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_control) ?

Answer (score 5):

From what I know, ROS Jade didn't support gazebo_ros_control so far. That's being from the major update of gazebo from 2.x to 5.x. that being said, it looks like this package is again put on use and `is unstable for the moment`. The [link](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros_control) here provides better information as well as the github source. you can use that by `making it under your catkin_ws with catkin_make`.
Cheers,

Comment: Thank you, Yassin and user6282718. Both of you point to the same website and it works!